# Reload image does not apply to the actual shader

Tags: texturing, materials, image

As you can see in this **[video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/zmmnSCMoDtw3Epej9)**, the image updates automatically in the image library. I even hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in the *Image Editor*, even though the image has been already updated, but in the Shader Editor the image remains that in buffer.

Even trying to reload the same image will not replace the one in the buffer.
The only way is to load another image, and then reload the right one.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: While it's not the same use case, I use this addon to help with a similar process. I pinned the Reload function to the Q menu so I can get to it from any viewport and it works a treat for reloading images from disk: https://github.com/samytichadou/Auto_Reload-Blender_addon

Comment: Thank you very much!